# I dont know why x.bandwidth = 0 in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to make a combograph by d3.js but I have a problem width my graph, I follow this example

https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_grouped_basicWide.html

to make columns to group bar chart into my graph but when i console to display value x.bandwidth (x.bandwidth = 0 ) so my graph disappear.

this is my code graph , It work i called by a API , thanks your help.

````
    const $panel = $(`#${panelUniqueId}`).find('.panel');
    $panel.empty();
  var data = [
        { name: "01:00", sales: 3500, forecast: 7000 },
        { name: "02:00", sales: 3500, forecast: 7000 },
        { name: "03:00", sales: 3500, forecast: 7000 },
        { name: "04:00", sales: 3500, forecast: 7000 },
        { name: "05:00", sales: 3500, forecast: 7000 },
        { name: "06:00", sales: 3500, forecast: 7000 },
        { name: "07:00", sales: 3500, forecast: 7000 },
        { name: "08:00", sales: 3500, forecast: 7000 },
        { name: "09:00", sales: 3500, forecast: 7000 },
        { name: "10:00", sales: 2800, forecast: 4500 },
        { name: "11:00", sales: 3600, forecast: 3300 },
        { name: "12:00", sales: 1700, forecast: 4700 },
        { name: "13:00", sales: 2200, forecast: 5500 },
        { name: "14:00", sales: 2500, forecast: 6500 },
        { name: "15:00", sales: 1500, forecast: 7500 },
        { name: "16:00", sales: 2000, forecast: 4100 },
        { name: "17:00", sales: 2500, forecast: 8000 },
        { name: "18:00", sales: 3500, forecast: 7000 },
        { name: "19:00", sales: 3500, forecast: 7000 },
        { name: "20:00", sales: 3500, forecast: 7000 },
        { name: "21:00", sales: 3500, forecast: 7000 },
        { name: "22:00", sales: 3500, forecast: 7000 },
        { name: "23:00", sales: 3500, forecast: 7000 },
        { name: "24:00", sales: 3500, forecast: 9000 },
    ];



    if (response.panelTitle === null || response.panelTitle === '') {
        $panel = '<div class="main-image" style=" width: 100%; height: 100%;pos"> <div class="row">';
    } else {
        $panel.append(`<h1 id="POG-LBL-001" style="padding: 1rem; margin-bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: 4.0rem; font-size: 1.5rem;"><p><strong>${response.panelTitle}</strong></p></h1>`);
        $panel.append('<div class="main-image" style="margin: 0 1rem 1rem 1rem; width: calc(100% - 2rem); height: calc(100% - 6rem); position:relative; pos"></div>')
    }
    if (response.url != null || response.url != "") {
        $(`#${panelUniqueId}`).find('#POG-LBL-001').on('click', function() {
            window.open(response.url);
        });
    }

    var getDatasetFordisplayGraph = response.dataSetForDisplayGraph;
    var getDisplaycolors = response.displayColors;
    var getComboGraphType = response.comboGraphType;
    var getYaxisScalemax = response.yaxisScaleMax;
    var getYaxisScalemin = response.yaxisScaleMin;
    var getYaxisScalesplit = response.yaxisScaleSplit;


    var getGuidedisplayFlag = response.guideDisplayFlg;

    var dataLegend;
    var dataForGraph = [];



    //Custom data to draw map
    for (i = 0; i < getDatasetFordisplayGraph.length; i++) {
        var map = {};
        for (j = 0; j < getDatasetFordisplayGraph[i].length; j++) {
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(getDatasetFordisplayGraph[i][j])) {
                map[`${key}`] = `${value}`;
            }
        }
        dataForGraph.push(map);
    }

    //  var arrayGroupBar = dataForGraph.map(ele => {
    //      var tempItem = Object.assign({}, ele);
    //      if (tempItem.time != undefined) {
    //          delete tempItem.time;
    //          return tempItem;
    //      } else if (tempItem.area != undefined) {
    //          delete tempItem.area;
    //          return tempItem;
    //      } else if (tempItem.factory != undefined) {
    //          delete tempItem.factory;
    //          return tempItem;
    //      } else if (tempItem.machine != undefined) {
    //          delete tempItem.machine;
    //          return tempItem;
    //      }
    //  });
    //
    //  console.log(arrayGroupBar);


    dataLegend = getDatasetFordisplayGraph[0].filter(ele => {
        if (!ele.time != undefined) {
            return !ele.time;
        } else if (!ele.area != undefined) {
            return !ele.area;
        } else if (!ele.factory != undefined) {
            return !ele.factory;
        } else if (!ele.machine != undefined) {
            return !ele.machine;
        }
    }).map(ele => Object.keys(ele)[0]);


    var dataOx = [];

    dataOx.push(getYaxisScalemax, getYaxisScalemin, getYaxisScalesplit, getDisplaycolors, getComboGraphType, dataLegend);

    //transform column to row
    const transpose = a => a[0].map((_, c) => a.map(r => r[c]));


    const rows = transpose(dataOx);

    var columns = ["max", "min", "split", "color", "type", "legend"];

    const assemblyData = (columns, rows) => {
        return rows.map((row) => {
            return row.reduce((res, field, index) => {
                res[columns[index]] = field;
                return res
            }, {});
        });
    }

    var customedObject = assemblyData(columns, rows);

    //console.log(customedObject);

    var data = dataForGraph;

    d3.select('.main-image').append('div').classed('row', true).style("height", "100%").style("width", "100%").style("margin", "unset")
        .append('div').attr('id', 'POG-GRP-002').classed('w-80', true).style("height", "100%");

    var margin = { top: 50, right: 100, bottom: 40, left: 140 },
        width = $('#POG-GRP-002').width() - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = $('#POG-GRP-002').height() - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        svg = d3.select('.w-80')
            .style('max-width', 'max-content')
            .style('height', 'max-content')
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    //  var dataOx = data.map(function(d) {
    //          if (d.time != undefined) {
    //              return d.time;
    //          } else if (d.area != undefined) {
    //              return d.area;
    //          } else if (d.factory != undefined) {
    //              return d.factory;
    //          } else if (d.machine != undefined) {
    //              return d.machine;
    //          }
    //      });

    var dataOx = d3.map(data, function(d) {
        if (d.time != undefined) {
            return d.time;
        } else if (d.area != undefined) {
            return d.area;
        } else if (d.factory != undefined) {
            return d.factory;
        } else if (d.machine != undefined) {
            return d.machine;
        }
    });

    console.log(dataOx);


    var x = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(dataOx)
        .rangeRound([0, width])
        .paddingInner(0.05);

    var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(dataLegend)
        .rangeRound([0, x.bandwidth()])
        .padding([0.05]);


    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

    console.log("default domain-range: ", x.domain());
    console.log("custom range-range: ", x.range());
    console.log("custom innerPadding: ", x.paddingInner());
    console.log("custom outerPadding: ", x.paddingOuter());
    console.log("Check step = bandwidth+paddingInner: ", xScale.step());
    console.log("Check bandWidth: ", x.bandwidth());



    svg.append('g')
        .attr('id', 'POG-GRP-002-001')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + (height - margin.bottom) + ')')
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-0.8em")
        .attr("dy", "-0.6em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

    var moveOyLeft = 0;
    var moveOfRight = 0;

    let legend = d3.select('.main-image .row').append("div").attr('id', 'POG-LBL-003').classed("w-20", true).style("padding-top", "4rem");

    var arrayLeft = [];
    var arrayRight = [];

    customedObject.forEach((element) => {
        if (element["type"] == 0) {
            arrayLeft.push(element);
        } else if (element["type"] == 1) {
            arrayRight.push(element);
        }
    });

    //console.log(arrayLeft);
    //console.log(arrayRight);

    var yindex;
    var yAxisindex;

    // lọc lấy max min và split 
    const uniques = [...new Set(
        arrayLeft.map(x => JSON.stringify((({ max, min, split }) => ({ max, min, split }))(x))))
    ].map(JSON.parse);


    if (uniques.length == 1) {
        var maxOne = parseFloat(uniques[0].max);
        var minOne = parseFloat(uniques[0].min);
        var splitOne = parseFloat(uniques[0].split);
        var tickOne = [];
        for (var i = minOne; i <= maxOne; i += splitOne) {
            tickOne.push(i);
        }

        d3.max(tickOne) == maxOne ? tickOne.push() : tickOne.push(maxOne);

        yindex = d3.scaleLinear().nice().domain([uniques[0].min, uniques[0].max])
            .range([height - margin.bottom, 0]);

        yAxisindex = d3.axisLeft(yindex).tickValues(tickOne);

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('id', 'POG-GRP-002-002')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + moveOyLeft + ',0)')
            .attr('class', 'y3-axis'.concat('-dn'))
            .attr('stroke', "#FFFF")
            .call(yAxisindex)
            .selectAll('.tick').attr('stroke', "#FFFF");
    }

    var itemLengend = [];


    arrayLeft.forEach((element, index) => {

        var legendUser = element["legend"];
        itemLengend.push(legendUser);

        if (uniques.length > 1) {

            var maxOy = parseFloat(element["max"]);
            var minOy = parseFloat(element["min"]);
            var splitOy = parseFloat(element["split"]);
            var tickCount = [];


            for (var i = minOy; i <= maxOy; i += splitOy) {
                tickCount.push(i);
            }

            d3.max(tickCount) == maxOy ? tickCount.push() : tickCount.push(maxOy);

            yindex = d3.scaleLinear().nice().domain([element["min"], element["max"]])
                .range([height - margin.bottom, 0]);

            yAxisindex = d3.axisLeft(yindex).tickValues(tickCount);

            svg.append('g')
                .attr('id', 'POG-GRP-002-002')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + moveOyLeft + ',0)')
                .attr('class', 'y3-axis'.concat('_' + index))
                .attr('stroke', element["color"])
                .call(yAxisindex)
                .selectAll('.tick text').attr('stroke', element["color"]).attr('fill', element["color"]);
            moveOyLeft -= 50;

            d3.select("#POG-GRP-002 svg").attr("width", (width + -(moveOyLeft) + 100));

            d3.select("#POG-GRP-002 svg g").attr('transform', 'translate(' + (margin.left + +"50") + ',' + margin.top + ')');
        }
        // ve hanrei

        if (getGuidedisplayFlag == 1) {
            let keys = legend.selectAll('.key')
                .data(itemLengend)
                .enter()
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'key')
                .style('display', 'flex')
                .style('align-items', 'center')
                .style('margin-right', '20px');

            keys.append('rect')
                .attr('class', 'symbol')
                .attr('id', 'POG-LBL-003-001')
                .style('height', '20px')
                .style('width', '20px')
                .style('margin', '5px 5px')
                .style('background-color', element["color"]);

            keys.append('text')
                .attr('class', 'name')
                .attr('id', 'POG-LBL-003-002')
                .text(function(d) { return d });

            keys.exit().remove();
        }
    });

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(dataLegend)
        .range(getDisplaycolors);

    var bar = svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'group-bar')
        .selectAll('g')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .attr('transform', function(d) {
            if (d.time != undefined) {
                return 'translate(' + x(d.time) + ',0)';
            } else if (d.area != undefined) {
                return 'translate(' + x(d.area) + ',0)';
            } else if (d.factory != undefined) {
                return 'translate(' + x(d.factory) + ',0)';
            } else if (d.machine != undefined) {
                return 'translate(' + x(d.machine) + ',0)';
            }
        });

    // バーチャート.
    bar.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d) {
            return dataLegend.map(function(key) {
                var a = { key: key, value: d[key] };
                //console.log(a);
                return a;
            });
        })
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'sales')
        .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.key); })
        .attr('x', function(d) {
            return x1(d.key);
        })
        .attr('y', function(d) {
            return yindex(d.value);
        })
        .attr('height', function(d) {
            //console.log((d[item]));
            return height - yindex(d.value) - margin.bottom;
        })
        .attr('width', x1.bandwidth());



    // vẽ đường line cho biểu đồ 

    //lọc lấy lấy max min split 
    const uniquesRight = [...new Set(
        arrayRight.map(x => JSON.stringify((({ max, min, split }) => ({ max, min, split }))(x))))
    ].map(JSON.parse);


    var y2;
    var yAxis2

    if (uniquesRight.length == 1) {

        var maxOne = parseFloat(uniquesRight[0].max);
        var minOne = parseFloat(uniquesRight[0].min);
        var splitOne = parseFloat(uniquesRight[0].split);
        var tickOne = [];
        for (var i = minOne; i <= maxOne; i += splitOne) {
            tickOne.push(i);
        }

        d3.max(tickOne) == maxOne ? tickOne.push() : tickOne.push(maxOne);

        y2 = d3.scaleLinear().nice()
            .domain([minOne, maxOne])
            .range([height - margin.bottom, 0]);

        yAxis2 = d3.axisRight(y2).tickValues(tickOne);

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('id', 'POG-GRP-002-004')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + Math.ceil(width + moveOfRight) + ',0)')
            .attr('class', 'y2-axis'.concat('-0'))
            .attr('stroke', "#FFFF")
            .call(yAxis2)
            .selectAll('.tick').attr('stroke', "#FFFF");

    }

    //var arrItem = [];
    //var reveredArr =  arrItem.reverse();
    var itemLengend2 = [];

    arrayRight.forEach((element, index) => {

        var legendUser = element["legend"];
        itemLengend2.push(legendUser);

        if (uniquesRight.length > 1) {

            var maxOy = parseFloat(element["max"]);
            var minOy = parseFloat(element["min"]);
            var splitOy = parseFloat(element["split"]);
            var tickCount = [];


            for (var i = minOy; i <= maxOy; i += splitOy) {
                tickCount.push(i);
            }

            d3.max(tickCount) == maxOy ? tickCount.push() : tickCount.push(maxOy);


            y2 = d3.scaleLinear().nice()
                .domain([element["min"], element["max"]])
                .range([height - margin.bottom, 0]);

            yAxis2 = d3.axisRight(y2).tickValues(tickCount);

            svg.append('g')
                .attr('id', 'POG-GRP-002-004')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + Math.ceil(width + moveOfRight) + ',0)')
                .attr('class', 'y2-axis'.concat('-' + index))
                .style('stroke', element["color"])
                .call(yAxis2);

            moveOfRight += 55;
        }


        //bắt đầu vẽ biểu đồ line ở đây 
        var linePlaceHolder = svg.append('g').attr("class", "line-percent");
        var percentLine = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) {
                if (d.time != undefined) {
                    return x(d.time);
                } else if (d.area != undefined) {
                    return x(d.area);
                } else if (d.factory != undefined) {
                    return x(d.factory);
                } else if (d.machine != undefined) {
                    return x(d.machine);
                }

            })
            //.x(function(d){return x(d.time)})
            .y(function(d) {
                //console.log(d);
                return y2(d[legendUser]);
            });

        linePlaceHolder.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .classed('line', true)
            .attr('stroke-width', '3px')
            .attr('stroke', element["color"])
            .attr("d", percentLine);

        // ve hanrei cho line
        if (getGuidedisplayFlag == 1) {

            let keysLegend = legend.selectAll('.key-strain')
                .data(itemLengend2)
                .enter().append('g')
                .attr('class', 'key-strain')
                .style('display', 'flex')
                .style('align-items', 'center')
                .style('margin-right', '20px');

            keysLegend.append('line')
                .attr('class', 'symbol')
                .attr('id', 'POG-LBL-003-001')
                .style('height', '5px')
                .style('width', '30px')
                .style('margin', '5px 5px')
                .style('background-color', element["color"]);

            keysLegend.append('text')
                .attr('class', 'name')
                .attr('id', 'POG-LBL-003-002')
                .text(function(d) { return d });

            keysLegend.exit().remove();
        }

    });

    // 横線を描画する
    d3.select('y2-axis-0').selectAll('g').filter(function(d) { return d; })
        .append('line')
        .attr('x2', -width)
        .attr('x1', 0)
        .attr('stroke', '#777')
        .attr('stroke-dasharray', 4)
        .attr('opacity', 0.5)




    //Select Date button
    var form = d3.select("[id='" + panelUniqueId + "']")
        .select('[class="main-image"]')
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'datePick')
        .style('width', '100%')
        .style('height', '20px')
        .style('background-color', '#262626')
        .append("form")
        .style("float", "left")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("bottom", "-1rem")

    // 前日ボタン
    form.append("button")
        .style("background-color", "#262626")
        .style("width", "20px")
        .style("height", "20px")
        .attr("id", "POG-TXT-006")
        .attr("type", "button")
        .attr("onclick", "POGpreviousButton(event,\'" + panelUniqueId + "\')")
        .append("i")
        .attr("class", "fas fa-caret-left")
        .style("font-size", "20px")
        .style("color", "white")
    // 対象日 日付ボックス
    form.append("input")
        .attr("type", "text")
        .attr("id", "POG-TXT-005")
        .attr("autocomplete", "off")
        .attr("onSelect", "hasdataPickerValue(event,\'" + panelUniqueId + "\')")
        .style("width", "140px")
        .style("height", "20px")
        .style("padding-top", "6px")
        .style("background-color", "#262626")
        .style("color", "white")
        .style("border-style", "solid")
        .style("border-width", "1px")
    // 本日ボタン 
    form.append("input")
        .attr("id", "POG-TXT-007")
        .attr("type", "button")
        .attr("value", "   ")
        .attr("onclick", "POGnowFunction(event,\'" + panelUniqueId + "\')")
        .style('height', '20px')
        .style('width', '20px')
        .style("border-radius", "50%")
        .style("background-color", "white")
    // 翌日ボタン
    form.append("button")
        .style("background-color", "#262626")
        .style('height', '20px')
        .style('width', '20px')
        .attr("id", "POG-TXT-008")
        .attr("type", "button")
        .attr("onclick", "POGnextButton(event,\'" + panelUniqueId + "\')")
        .append("i")
        .attr("class", "fas fa-caret-right")
        .style("font-size", "20px")
        .style("color", "white")


    $('#POG-TXT-005').val(formatDatePCG(date))
    $('#POG-TXT-005').datepicker(
        {
            dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
            onSelect: function(dateText) {
                date = new Date(dateText)
                reGrapDraw(panelUniqueId, formatDatePCG(date))

            }
        });

}



//call api if click button
function POGpreviousButton(e, panelUniqueId) {
    e.preventDefault();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
    $('#POG-TXT-005').val(formatDatePCG(date))
    reGrapDraw(panelUniqueId, formatDatePCG(date))
}

function POGnextButton(e, panelUniqueId) {
    e.preventDefault();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    $('#POG-TXT-005').val(formatDatePCG(date))
    reGrapDraw(panelUniqueId, formatDatePCG(date))
}

function POGnowFunction(e, panelUniqueId) {
    e.preventDefault();
    date = new Date()
    $('#POG-TXT-005').val(formatDatePOG(date))
    reGrapDraw(panelUniqueId, formatDatePCG(date))
}

function formatDatePOG(d) {

    var month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
    var day = '' + d.getDate();
    var year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('/');
}

function reGrapDraw(panelUniqueId, dateSelected) {
    console.log("getAPI")
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/panel/POG',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { 'panelUniqueId': panelUniqueId, 'date': dateSelected },
        success: function(response) {
            genPanelPOG(panelUniqueId, response);
        }
    });

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem

in `var x = d3.scaleBand() .domain(dataOx) .rangeRound([0, width]) .padding(1);`
have to change padding(0.05) make it same padding of x1.